# How do I use the enum type from a class in another part of code?

Tags: c++

Been trying to use a polymorphic method to change a enum type from one class to another which is also protected.
37|error: expected primary-expression before 'skeletonType'. Do I have to declare another set of enumerated types?

```
    enum Skeleton_Type { NONE, HYDROSTATIC, EXOSKELETON };
    class Invertebrate {
      private:
        string name;
        Skeleton_Type skeletonType;
      protected:
        void setSkeletonType(Skeleton_Type skeletonType);
    class Spider : public Invertebrate 
    void setSkeleton (Skeleton_Type skeletonType)
    {
  (37)          Invertebrate::setSkeletonType(Skeleton_Type skeletonType);
        }
```

Comment: Please learn the basic syntax of the language before doing esoteric stuff. `Invertebrate::setSkeletonType(Skeleton_Type skeletonType);` That's not how you call a function. `Skeleton_Type skeletonType` is a declaration. You cannot use a declaration as an actual function argument, it makes no sense. You need an expression. Try `Invertebrate::setSkeletonType(skeletonType);`

Comment: Proper indentation would be nice.

Comment: thanks @n.m  Just not used to using enum types :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of syntax issues with the code you've provided, but in the case of the specific error you've presented, this is because the call:

```
Invertebrate::setSkeletonType(Skeleton_Type skeletonType);
```

has the type of the argument in the parameter list; this line should simply read:

```
Invertebrate::setSkeletonType(skeletonType);
```

Further issues include no closing brace/semicolon at the end of your `Invertebrate` class declaration and no braces/semicolon enclosing the body of your `Spider` class. These may not be contributing to the error in question, but they're certainly going to cause compilation issues even if you fix the above.